# Error when installing software in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am running jupyter notebooks but when trying to install software with:

```
!pip install ipython-sql
```

it returns this error:

```
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/prettytable.py -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prettytable.py'
```

And below, in red letter:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-6I8SLA/prettytable/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-nL3KsL-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-6I8SLA/prettytable/
```

That is all information I have. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: This looks like a permission issue. Have you tried running pip or jupyter with sudo?

Comment: Thanks @Matt. I don't know how to run sudo in jupyter-notebook. I have tried `sudo !pip install ipython-sql` but that seems wrong.

Comment: Try using !sudo pip install ipython-sql

Comment: The command works but it asks for the key, and when writing the key nothing is installed @Matt

Comment: I opened jupyter notebooks using `jupyter notebooks --allow-root` and then installed the programm. But I don't know why superuser can't be used once opened jupyter @Matt

Comment: I was wrong, it doesn't work neither @Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated your problem and solved it using:

```
!pip install ipython-sql --user
```

I use Linux Mint and Python 3.4. Using the --user flag stores libraries in your home directory, in my case under ~/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages.